# using windows debugger to view a memory location written to in C?

Tags: c, windows, debugging, assembly, turbo-c

I have Turbo C and windows debug running in dosbox

I have this C program, it has two main lines, as you can see.   `int a=5` and then a line to show the address of a,  `printf("address of a=%x",&a)`

[image]

I run it

[image]

It seems to tell me that a has been allocated the address of fff4

Now I want to use debug to hopefully see the value of 5 at that memory address

But it is not showing

[image]

How can I see it in debug?

Comment: Once your program exits then any temporary changes to memory are effectively gone. You need to debug *while your program is running* - set a breakpoint in the program and then examine memory while it's halted at the breakpoint.

Comment: That is virtual address. Its different for each process.

Comment: @PaulR , rohan, So is it possible to write a C program that writes to RAM in a non temporary way?

Comment: @barlop: in some embedded environments you might be able to, but in general no - RAM is temporary, and in most modern operating systems it's virtual memory space anyway, so once your process is gone then the addresses and memory contents have no meaning.

Comment: Can you give us a little bit more details why you want to do this ? What is your goal ? In a real dos 16 bit environment - which you are targetting with turbo c - you could write to memory outside of your process and have this change survive the exit of your program.

Comment: @Marged my goal is to play with debug and C and see memory. I suppose I will see if I can get it all running off an emulated thing and update my question if it still fails

Comment: Then use a dos VM and run a program in it which writes to for example the video memory. Then you will be able to persist data which stays there until you reboot

Comment: @barlop - On a meta level: The demand for debugging skills on 16-bit DOS isn't that great anymore. I haven't use mine since the 1980's. Perhaps you should consider something else to study? And use a tool from this millennium?

Comment: @Marged I have a VM with DOS 6.22  What lines of C/C++ would write to a specific memory location? (If that's a big question, i'll write a new question for it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my DEBUG's output of the compiled `main` function:

```
16E1:01FA 55            PUSH    BP                                 
16E1:01FB 8BEC          MOV BP,SP                              
16E1:01FD 83EC02        SUB SP,+02                             
16E1:0200 C746FE0500    MOV WORD PTR [BP-02],0005              
16E1:0205 8D46FE        LEA AX,[BP-02]                         
16E1:0208 50            PUSH    AX                                 
16E1:0209 B89401        MOV AX,0194                            
16E1:020C 50            PUSH    AX                                 
16E1:020D E8AA06        CALL    08BA                               
16E1:0210 59            POP CX                                 
16E1:0211 59            POP CX                                 
16E1:0212 8BE5          MOV SP,BP                              
16E1:0214 5D            POP BP                                 
16E1:0215 C3            RET
```

`int a=5;` is a **local** variable inside the function `main` which is stored on the stack (`MOV WORD PTR [BP-02],0005`). A value on the stack is lost, when you leave the function (`RET`). You cannot see it outside the running program.

Your plan can go well, if you

1. Initialize a global variable and
2. produce a tiny .com program.

**simplepr.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a=5;

void main()
{
    printf ("address of a=%x",&a);
}
```

**Compile:**

```
TCC.EXE -mt -lt simplepr.c
```

**DEBUG session:**

```
n simplepr.com
l
g         -> address of a=125c (example)
d 125c    -> or what the address is
```

Comment: thanks, that looks fascinating, i'd like to try it.. I have DOS 6.22 in a VM in virtualbox, and I have debug and my EXE.. How did you get the assembly instructions of the EXE(that you show at the beginning of your answer)?

Comment: @barlop. In DEBUG the command 'u'. I used Turbo Debugger to get the address of "_main".

Comment: I can't quite get there   http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0jDA.png   I can't get it outputting a memory location, and if you can include the turbo debugger command to get the address of _main then even better.

Comment: @barlop: '**d** 1562' like "**d**ump"! 'g' is "go" and '?' is "help" ;-) The explanation with Turbo Debugger is a little bit complicated. Have you installed Turbo Debugger and which version?

Comment: I see it , when int a=5, the 5 is there  http://i.imgur.com/X0bdtxh.png   and http://i.imgur.com/PL66kGc.png      thanks

Comment: @barlop: The dump begins at  a paragraph boundary (1560). Because you want to see it from 1562 the first two places (1560, 1561) are blank. Then you see your int (16 bits = 2 bytes, little endian) '05 00'. After that is the format string of `printf` which is also stored in the global area.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91497/discussion-between-barlop-and-rkhb).